# Code for a random background-image every time the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am working on an html-file that is supposed to show a new backround-image everytime the page is refreshed. This HTML-file is placed in a directory called "Startsida".**
The images backgroundphoto1, backgroundphoto2 and backgroundphoto3 are placed in a folder called "images".
There's still something wrong with my code and I don't know how to fix it.

I don't know if it's worth noting, but this code is made on visual studios.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- The randomator -->

    <script>
      var images = [
        "../images/photobackground1.jpg",
        "../images/photobackground2.jpg",
        "../images/photobackground3.jpg",
      ];
      function randomator() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("bg")[0].style.backgroundImage =
          "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")";
      }
      randomator();
    </script>

    <style>
      body,
      html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .bg {
        /* Full height */
        height: 100%;

        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">randomator</div>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: where is your element with class .mainview?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you have several misunderstandings regarding the fundamentals of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.  I'll break these issues down for you, sorted by language.  At the very bottom, you'll find a completely fixed version that works perfectly.

### HTML

##### Closing tags

Tags with child elements *must* be opened and closed.  You wrote:

```html
<div> randomator.bg <div>
```

The correct syntax is:

```html
<div> randomator.bg </div>
```

Without the slash in the closing tag, there's no way for the browser to know where an element starts or ends.

##### Classes

You can't give a class to an HTML `div` by simply writing `.classname` inside.  You have to add the class attribute to the opening tag.  You wrote:

```html
<div> randomator.bg </div>
```

The correct syntax is:

```html
<div class="bg"> randomator </div>
```

### JavaScript

##### Line endings

Semicolons should only be used at the very end of a line of JavaScript code.  You wrote:

```js
randomator(); {
    ...
}
```

The correct syntax is:

```js
randomator() {
    ...
}
```

##### Function definitions

You must provide either the `function` identifier or use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) when defining a function.  You wrote:

```js
randomator() {
    ...
}
```

The correct syntax is:

```js
function randomator() {
    ...
}
```

##### Class matching with HTML

You need to select the correct element if you want to change its background.  If you've been following along from above, you should only have an element with a class of `bg`.  You wrote:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("mainview")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")";
```

The correct syntax is:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("bg")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")";
```

### CSS

##### JavaScript vs CSS

JavaScript and CSS are two different languages, and though JavaScript does have the ability to change CSS properties, the two don't share variables.  You wrote:

```css
background-image: mainview;
```

There's no way to do this exactly, though you could technically use JS to change [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).  In your case, I'd recommend just removing this line entirely.

### Complete example

The code below should work perfectly - all bugs have been fixed.

```js
var images = ["images/photokacround1.jpg", "images/photobackround2.jpg", "images/photobackround3.jpg"];

function randomator() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("mainview")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")";
}
randomator();
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainview {
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainview"> randomator </div>
```

Comment: I can't describe in words how much I appreciate your help about my misunderstandings. I have taken everything to heart, but it still doesn't seem to work. The only thing that happens is word 'randomator' being displayed. How do I proceed? – @micahlt

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that the `images` folder is in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: No, they were not. Thanks for noticing! I just tried to set all of the pictures to "..//images/photokacround1.jpg", but it still doesn't work for some reason. I also tried "../images/photokacround1.jpg". This file that I have written is on another file than images.

Comment: I also spelled photobackground1 correctly

Comment: Could you explain exactly how your folders are laid out, or even update your question with a screenshot of how they're laid out?  Also, are you running the HTML directly or with a server of some kind?

Comment: There we go. The question is updated

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it! the problem is that I didn't mention the  as javascript! In this part...**

var images = [
        "../images/photobackground1.jpg",
        "../images/photobackground2.jpg",
        "../images/photobackground3.jpg",
      ];
      function randomator() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("bg")[0].style.backgroundImage =
          "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")";
      }
      randomator();

> **...Is was supposed to mention < script type="text/javascript"> and then ending it of with < script>.**

While I was using that I was supposed to write

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    randomator();
    </script>
```

I have tested the code and it now works! This is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- The randomator -->

    <script  type="text/javascript">
      var images = [
        "../images/bakgrundbilder/photobackground1.jpg",
        "../images/bakgrundbilder/photobackground2.jpg",
        "../images/bakgrundbilder/photobackground3.jpg",
      ];
      function randomator() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("bg")[0].style.backgroundImage =
          "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ")";
      }
      randomator();
    </script>

    <style>
      body,
      html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .bg {
        /* Full height */
        height: 100%;

        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      } </style>   </head>   <body>
    <div class="bg">   </body>   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    randomator();
    </script> </html>
```

**Just don't forget to replace the backgroundimages and reference them correctly!**